# Changing expression from sync to async

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have the following expression :

```
    var rules = rules.OrderBy(rule => (int)rule.RuleType)
    .FirstOrDefault( item  =>  item.IsMatch(request.data))
    ?.Execute(request.data);
```

What this piece of code does - it takes a set of rules (which all implement the same interface),

sorts them in ascending order, and then calls the IsMatch function that each one of these rules implements - the first 'True' that returns from any IsMatch function will stop the iteration and call the `Execute` function.

If all returned False, `Execute` will not be called.

The `rules` object is at the beginning (after the OrderBy) a `IOrderedEnumerable<IRule>` , and later changes to `IEnumerable<IRule>` (the type FirstOrDefault returns).

I am refactoring some of my code, now the `isMatch` function has changed to an Async function.

I am using .NET 472 and found that the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` that is in the `EntityFramework.DynamicLinq` namespace, can only be called on an `IQueryable` type of object.

Once I change it to :

```
 var rules = rules.OrderBy(rule => (int)rule.RuleType).ToList().AsQueryable()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(async item  => await item.IsMatchAsync(request.data))
    ?.Execute(request.data);
```

I get an error that there is no overload to the FirstOrDefaultAsync function that accepts a boolean (or in this case lambda that returns booleans)

So my question is - how can I change this code to asynchronous code?

Comment: Is it an option to install the package [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) to your project? There are a lot of extension methods for `IAsyncEnumerable`s there.

Comment: I have installed it now, Im still facing an issue - the await should be right before the IsMatchAsync call. I have tried to change it to
rules.OrderBy(rule => (int) rule.RuleType).ToAsyncEnumerable().Where(async item => await item.IsMatchAsync(request.data));
And it says
Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type 'Func<IRule,bool>'. An async lambda expression my return boid,Task or Task<T>, none of which are convertible to 'Func<IRule,bool>' @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the library [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/), and assuming that the `Rule` class contains the methods `public Task<bool> IsMatchAsync(string arg)` and `public Task ExecuteAsync(string arg)`:

```
var matchedRule = await rules.ToAsyncEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(rule => (int)rule.RuleType)
    .FirstOrDefaultAwaitAsync(async item => await item.IsMatchAsync(request.data));
if (matchedRule != null) await matchedRule.ExecuteAsync(request.data);
```